# Ionic 6 (Angular) toast message never show up on the screen

Tags: ionic-framework, toast, ionic6

I am currently using browser to test the application. I've implemented the toast message like in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast). Although the element is generated on the html when I look in the Elements with z-index: 60002.

**landing.page.ts** file:

```
    import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';
    import { Platform, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-landing',
      templateUrl: './landing.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./landing.page.scss'],
    })
    export class LandingPage implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private platform: Platform, public toastController: ToastController) { }
    
    
      async presentToast(){
        const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: 'Your settings have been saved.',
          duration: 100000,
          position: 'middle'
        });
    
        toast.present();
      }

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**landing.page.html** file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>landing</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-button (click)="presentToast()">Pair</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

I also changed the position to top, bottom and middle nothing changed.

PS: I did't edited any css file.

Comment: your code seems to work on stackblitz. Do you have any error message in the console ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-y2n5p9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: No I don't have any errors, even I see the tost element occur in page source as HTML but not visible at all.

Comment: I had a problem with popover on iOS that was showed outside of the screen because of a height problem, with Ionic 6. The fix was to attribue a height. In your css try, ion-toast { --height: 50px;}